# Make sure a specific setInterval function instance is running only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I'm working on a div (parent) that has two other divs (menu and content) as follow:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="menu"></div>
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

The content loaded in content div is an html file that has a few javascript functions, such as an auto-refresh that reloads its content every 5 seconds.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  setInterval(function () {
    grid.reloadDefaultContent(); //this reloads the content on content div.
  }, 5000);
}
```

There are some links on the page that load differents content into the content div. So far so good, until I go back to "home," which has the auto-refresh function. The problem is that the auto-refresh never stopped, and now that I clicked to go to home again, the function is running twice (or how many times I change the page and come back to home), putting session upon.
I'm loading pages using jQuery `$.load()`.

Any ideas on how I can make that instance of setInterval runs only once?

*Edit: after reading my own question I saw that it was a bit unclear. My main problem is that when I go back to home, my first instance of the setInterval is already running, and a second starts, making the auto-refresh that was 5 seconds go faster, and it'll go faster and faster every time I change the page and go back to home. This is not the behavior I want. What I need is to STOP the instance of setInterval when I change the content on the div, and restart it when I go back to home.*

Comment: What do you mean by "independent on the user changing the page/div content"?  It's not clear what that has to do with the timer issue.

Comment: How is `grid` defined? Is it global or inside a closure?

Comment: @Pointy: I took that as "I don't have the option to use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`". But I may be wrong...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var interval; // make sure that is defined outside of the loaded div content
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (typeof interval != "number"){
         interval = setInterval(function () {
         grid.reloadDefaultContent();
  }, 2000);
    }
});
```

It will only initiate one instance of the interval timer.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>If you only want it to run once, why not just use "setTimeout()" instead?</strike>

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if (!$('body').hasClass('refresh-started')) {
    setInterval(function () {
      grid.reloadDefaultContent(); //this reloads the content on content div.
    }, 5000);
    $('body').addClass('refresh-started');
  }
}
```

Another alternative would be to always *re-start* the timer instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  clearInterval($('body').data('refresh-interval'));
  $('body').data('refresh-interval', setInterval(function() {
    grid.reloadDefaultContent(); //this reloads the content on content div.
  }, 5000));
});
```

Which one is better depends on your circumstances.

Comment: If I understood his question correctly, that javascript gets added to the page through an ajax load. He does want it to work as an interval, but does not want it to be repeatedly initiated every time someone opens that tab/page with the ajax load during the same session.

Comment: Yes Niklas, I figured that out eventually.  Thanks :-)

Comment: The OP unfortunately states: "independent on the user changing the page/div content"

Comment: @Ates Goral yes he does say that but I do not know what it means :-)

Comment: Neither do I, really. I just deleted that sentence. I'll try this solution in a second. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to only run once, you should use [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setTimeout) not `setInterval()`.

Answer (score 0):

User jQuery's [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one) function

> **Description**: Attach a handler to an
>   event for the elements. The handler is
>   executed at most once per element.

```
$("#foo").one("click", function() {
  alert("This will be displayed only once.");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the source page that does the `setInterval`, your only option seems to be to hack the `grid.reloadDefaultContent` function to make it run only once. It is impossible to provide any recommendations without seeing how `grid` is defined.